# Remove seconds from dateTime in XQUERY

Tags: xml, xquery, oracle-ebs

So i have a dateTime like "2022-06-25T03:00:00+02:00" and i have to just remove the seconds and retain everything else.

eg: "2022-06-25T03:00+02:00"

Below is the input xml, i have to tranform the data to match the eg: that i ahve mentioned above.

Could someone please help?
Note: I am new to XQuery, so please tell me what is that your xquery doing too.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message xsi:schemaLocation="http://abcd.ch http://abcd.ch/ns/Message.xsd" xmlns="http://abcd.ch/ns/Message" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <messageId>4894954fyfuguyutfu_98798_98798</messageId>
 <messageType>Message</messageType>
 <messageDate>2022-06-23T12:49:11+02:00</messageDate>
</Message>
```

**Expected output XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Nomination xmlns="http://www.example.com" Release="1" Version="EGAS40">
    <Identification v="ABC123"/>
    <Type v="55G"/>
    <messageDate v="2022-06-23T12:49+02:00"/>
</Nomination>
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your RDBMS and its version .
All within the question, no images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach is using `fn:replace` with RegEx:

```
replace(xs:string($file/dateTimeValue),'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}):\d{2}(\+\d{2}:\d{2})','$1$2')
```

Result is

> 2022-06-25T03:00+02:00

You could not convert the resulting string back to an `xs:dateTime` because, well, it would be wrong format (obviously).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I am using the dateTime as xs:dateTime and here the regex is expecting a string. So this method is not working.
The dateTime cannot be converted to string because this is used in a loop and other functions is expecting a dateTime and not string. Is there a different way?

Comment: Just convert the `xs:dateTime` to an `xs:string`. I updated my answer to do that. Converting it back wouldn't be possible, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your XQuery processor supports XQuery 3.0, you could use the [`format-dateTime()` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-format-dateTime) with [a picture string](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-format-dateTime) that excludes the seconds:

```
let $date := "2022-06-23T12:49:11+02:00"
return
    $date
    => xs:dateTime()
    => format-dateTime("[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[h01]:[m01][Z]")
```

This returns `"2022-06-23T12:49+02:00"`.

If you're not familiar with `=>`, see [Arrow operator](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-arrow-operator).

All of these links point to the current version of the official XQuery specification, XQuery 3.1.

Comment: Hi @Joe, This method is throwing an error. so i am assuming this method is not compatible in Xquery2004 version. Is it possible you can provide me with something else?

Comment: Hi Ammu, My code works with modern XQuery engines like Saxon, eXist, and BaseX. I'm not sure what your processor is, but you might check your product's documentation and if it doesn't support XQuery 3.1, request support for it because of the useful functions and structures it adds.